# ListBox Control in VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am currently working on a multi branch desktop based project using VB.NET 2008.

My Admin want to see the list of currently working branches and not working branches. Additionally they want to know how long a branch is not working.

To display the offline branches I first take a ListBox control named lstListBranch and then upon that control I take another ListBox control named lstListTime to display the offline time.

I want to permanently hide the scrollbar for lstListTime control and want to scroll lstListTime when lstListBranch is scrolled. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just to be clear is this web or desktop program/control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my code in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/70b4ae57-01b6-4708-9f38-7879916f8b18/) for a trick to keep list boxes scrolling in-sync.  Turning off the scrollbar requires overriding the CreateParams property:

```
Public Class MyListBox
  Inherits ListBox

  Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
      Dim parms As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
      parms.Style = parms.Style And Not &H200000      ' turn off WS_VSCROLL
      Return parms
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of a custom list that has the ability for the scroll to be hidden [here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidF0FDB984AB0429D0E6DF5D90B0A30F850D0335DB.aspx)

Comment: This code is written in C#. But I want VB.NET Code. Thanks for the help.